# Draft an aggregate to group based on a nested attribute with lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

There are these two collections as listed below

```
orders: [
  {
    "_id": "64355c928dcce8cdf4b9c7d2",
    "destinations": [
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92af10d37993473e12", // mongoose id from locations collection
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2" // mongoose id from locations collection
      },
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92ed8af3f7cd7199b2"
      },
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92256aa652e6c3fdc5",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c924f9a2fcafa90daed"
      }
    ],
    "contact_details": [
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "aaa",
        "sold_to_ref": "bbb",
        "contact_email": "a@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "bbb",
        "sold_to_ref": "ccc",
        "contact_email": "b@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "ddd",
        "sold_to_ref": "eee",
        "contact_email": "c@gmail.com",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "64355c92bf25e54cf901be39",
    "destinations": [
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2"
      },
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92ed8af3f7cd7199b2"
      },
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92256aa652e6c3fdc5"
      }
    ],
    "contact_details": [
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "aaa",
        "sold_to_ref": "bbb",
        "contact_email": "a@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "bbb",
        "sold_to_ref": "ccc",
        "contact_email": "b@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "aaa",
        "sold_to_ref": "ddd",
        "contact_email": "d@gmail.com",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "64355c921445785f4b50040e",
    "destinations": [
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2"
      },
      {
        "ship_to_id": "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
        "sold_to_id": "64355c92ed8af3f7cd7199b2"
      }
    ],
    "contact_details": [
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "aaa",
        "sold_to_ref": "bbb",
        "contact_email": "a@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "ship_to_ref": "aaa",
        "sold_to_ref": "ccc",
        "contact_email": "e@gmail.com",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

and

```
locations: [
  {
    "_id": "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
    "reference_id": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2",
    "reference_id": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64355c92ed8af3f7cd7199b2",
    "reference_id": "ccc"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64355c92256aa652e6c3fdc5",
    "reference_id": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "_id": "64355c924f9a2fcafa90daed",
    "reference_id": "eee"
  },
]
```

Now what I want to achieve is write an aggregate query that groups me all the indents based on same ship_to, sold_to and contact_email (**Note**: to verify if thats a valid ship_to and sold_to we need to lookup from the `locations` collection using the `ship_to_id` and `sold_to_id`, retrieve the respective `reference_id 's` and then compare it with the `ship_to_ref` and `sold_to_ref` that is available in contact details) such that the query result will be like

```
[{
  _id: {
    ship_to_ref: "aaa",
    sold_to_ref: "bbb",
    ship_to_id:"64355c92af10d37993473e12"
    sold_to_id:"64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2"
    contact_email: "a@gmail.com"
   },
   orders: [
     { "_id": "64355c928dcce8cdf4b9c7d2", ... },
     { "_id": "64355c92bf25e54cf901be39", ... },
     { "_id" : "64355c921445785f4b50040e", ...}
   ],
 },
 {
  _id: {
    ship_to_ref: "bbb",
    sold_to_ref: "ccc",
    ship_to_id:"64355c92a57d8b29412a1cc2",
    sold_to_id:"64355c92ed8af3f7cd7199b2",
    contact_email: "b@gmail.com"
   },
   orders: [
     { "_id": "64355c928dcce8cdf4b9c7d2", ... },
     { "_id": "64355c92bf25e54cf901be39", ... },
   ],
 },
 {
  _id: {
    ship_to_ref: "ddd",
    sold_to_ref: "eee",
    ship_to_id: "64355c92256aa652e6c3fdc5",
    sold_to_id: "64355c924f9a2fcafa90daed",
    "contact_email": "c@gmail.com",
   },
   orders: [
     { "_id": "64355c928dcce8cdf4b9c7d2", ... }
   ],
 },
{
  _id: {
    ship_to_ref: "aaa",
    sold_to_ref: "ddd",
    ship_to_id: "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
    sold_to_id: "64355c92256aa652e6c3fdc5",
    contact_email: "d@gmail.com",
   },
   orders: [
     { "_id": "64355c92bf25e54cf901be39", ... }
   ],
 },
{
  _id: {
    ship_to_ref: "aaa",
    sold_to_ref: "ccc",
    ship_to_id: "64355c92af10d37993473e12",
    sold_to_id: "64355c92ed8af3f7cd7199b2",
    contact_email: "e@gmail.com",
   },
   orders: [
     { "_id": "64355c921445785f4b50040e", ... }
   ],
 },
]
```

Below is an aggregate query that I tried

```
[{
  $match: {
    contact_details: { $exists: true },
  },
},
{ $unwind: '$destinations' },
{ $unwind: '$contact_details'},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      sold_to_id: '$destinations.sold_to_id',
      ship_to_id: '$destinations.ship_to_id',
    }
    orders: {
      $push: {
        id: '$order_no', // order_no is an attribute from an order object
        contact_details: '$contact_details',
        destinations: '$destinations', // should contain all the destinations that were there initially inside an order entry
      },
    },
    type: { $first: { type: '$destinations.type' } },
  },
}]
```

but not sure how to incorporate a lookup and do the ref comparison and email check.
Need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so is it like same array index refer to same in dest and contact details arrays

Comment: nope the index won't be necessarily same, they can be jumbled as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `$map` before you `unwind`, so you can only `unwind` once and use `$indexOfArray` in order to match the references after the `$lookup`:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {$match: {contact_details: {$exists: true}}},
  {$project: {
      del: {$map: {
          input: {$range: [0, {$size: "$contact_details"}]},
          in: {
            destination: {$arrayElemAt: ["$destinations", "$$this"]},
            contact: {$arrayElemAt: ["$contact_details", "$$this"]},
            destinations: "$destinations"
          }
      }}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$del"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        sold_to_id: "$del.destination.sold_to_id",
        ship_to_id: "$del.destination.ship_to_id"
      },
      contact_email: {$first: "$del.contact.contact_email"},
      orders: {$push: {
          _id: "$_id", 
          contact_details: "$del.contact",
          destinations: "$del.destinations"
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {locations: ["$_id.sold_to_id", "$_id.ship_to_id"]}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "locations",
      localField: "locations",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "locations"
  }},
  {$project: {
      "_id.ship_to_id": "$_id.ship_to_id",
      "_id.sold_to_id": "$_id.sold_to_id",
      "_id.contact_email": "$contact_email",
      "_id.ship_to_ref": {$getField: {
          input: {$arrayElemAt: [
              "$locations",
              {$indexOfArray: ["$locations._id", "$_id.ship_to_id"]}
          ]},
          field: "reference_id"
      }},
      "_id.sold_to_ref": {$getField: {
          input: {$arrayElemAt: [
              "$locations",
              {$indexOfArray: ["$locations._id", "$_id.sold_to_id"]}
          ]},
          field: "reference_id"
      }},
      orders: 1
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y2vD3pdGljm)

Comment: Thanks @nimrod, but in the result, inside the orders array, in each object I expect destinations array just like the contact_details.
Please check the edited question

Comment: And this destinations array contain all the entries available for that order entry (as per the orders collection)

Comment: I updated the answer according to your first comment, added the `_id`. I don't understand the second comment

Comment: What I meant is just like you have added the _id right, I need the destinations array also to be present and that destinations array should contain all the entries similar to what is present in the orders collection for that order entry

Comment: With some minute tinkering, I was able to achieve that. Check this out.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/IhUSudc04Mx

By the way, Thanks again mate.

Comment: Also there is another approach that I did wherein the lookup happens through reference_id
Check this link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/axu-HCTt42h

Btw your solution is more promising since the lookup implementation is using mongoose id.

Comment: Updated the answer to add all destinations

Comment: I have a followup question, in the initial projection you are iteration through the destinations right, can we choose only those destinations where the field `type` doesn't exist or even if exists should be equal to null  ? Assume that the `type` is another field just like `ship_to_id` and `sold_to_id`

Comment: Yes, in this case I would use `$reduce` instead of `$map`

Comment: Could you pls add the new query below as an edit without modifying the existing query

Comment: Please ask a new question with the relevant example

Comment: I have created a new question. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992442/pull-out-specific-elements-based-on-if-a-field-exists-or-not-in-aggregate-pipeli